# How to remove multiple records from table based on a value?

Tags: spring

I have a table called `contacts`. This table has 5 columns: contact_id, localevent_id, name, email_adress, phone_number.

I have a method that creates a new record:

```
@PostMapping("/rest/contacts/new")
@ResponseBody
public ResponseEntity createContact(@RequestParam("contact") JSONObject contactString) {
    LoggingService.log("Contact new: " + contactString.toString());

    try {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        Contact contact = mapper.readValue(contactString.toString(), Contact.class);
        contactRepository.save(contact);
        return ResponseEntity.ok().header(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, "application/json")
                .body("\"Contactpersoon is succesvol toegevoegd of gewijzigd\"");
    }
    catch(IOException ioEx) {
        throw new DatabaseException("Fout bij het wegschrijven van de gegevens, neem contact op met het EventPointteam");
    }
    catch(RuntimeException ex) {
        throw new DatabaseException("Fout bij het wegschrijven van de gegevens, neem contact op met het EventPointteam");
    }
}
```

But now the database is getting polluted with records because the front-end function posts a new contact to the back-end:

```
if(this.validatePhone(this.contact.phone) && this.validateEmail(this.contact.email)){

    this.restCall.post("/contacts/new", formData, response => {
        this.showResult(response);
    });
}
```

A simple but dirty fix would be to first remove all the records that have a certain localevent_id and then post the new record that has that localevent_id. But I have very limited knowledge of the spring framework (this has been build by someone else). Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Instead of removing existing skip adding duplicates. before adding try to find whether DB already contains the record (e.g. by email, name and phone number ). If such a record is found just return the record rather than add a new one. I don't know your table structure may be it's fine to search by localevent_id.

Comment: I know it's badly programmed by our back-ender. But the idea is that when a user wants to edit his personal data it also uses the create method. So by first removing the old record and then placing the new record it looks like it's been edited. So that's what I'm trying to fix.